# Multiple site with multiple port in xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed xampp on windows. I have two folder in htdocs. siteA and siteB. I want open each site by diffrent port. For example for siteA i want to use http://localhost/siteA and for siteB http://localhost:2026/siteB.
SiteB must dosn't open with port 80.

Comment: no any one to answer me?

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/

What have you tried so far?